# Reading session object's value from memcached

Tags: php, symfony, session, memcached

I am using **memcached** as session handler in Symfony2 and changed the prefix for session from `memc.sess.key` to `session`.

Running:

> telnet localhost 11211
>
> get sessionbirajom0mlvda2mg9v3ieqjce4
>
> VALUE sessionbirajom0mlvda2mg9v3ieqjce4 0 185
>   _sf2_attributes|a:2:{s:9:"validated";b:1;s:18:"authenticated_user";a:1:{s:2:"id";s:2:"24";}}_sf2_flashes|a:0:{}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1455902113;s:1:"c";i:1455827153;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}

How do I read these session values back from **memcahed** in Symfony2?

Comment: Are you using the MemcachedSessionHandler? http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Session/Storage/Handler/MemcachedSessionHandler.html , or are you using a bundle or anything else?  How are you setting the value in the first place?

Comment: @JasonRoman i am using MemcachedSessionHandler , i am saving from code like `$session->set('value','xyz')` and it will be directly saved into memcache

Comment: If you already have that all configured properly can't you just use `$session->get('value');` to retrieve the data then?